# How to access the value of an unknown key?

Tags: json, key, jq

I have the following JSON file

```json
{
    "https://test.com/gg": [
        "msg",
        "popup",
        "url"
    ]
}
```

What I want to achieve is to parse the values to output the following

```
https://test.com/gg?msg=gg
https://test.com/gg?popup=gg
https://test.com/gg?url=gg
```

I'm assuming it can be done using jq but I'm not sure how.

The way i know is if the elemets were named like bellow:

```
{
    "url":"https://test.com/gg": [
        "p1":"msg",
    ]
}
```

I would pull the elements like:

`cat json | jq "url.[p1]"`

But in my case is it not named.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jq --raw-output 'to_entries[0] | .key as $url | .value[] | "\($url)?\(.)=gg"' <your json file here>
```

Where

1. `to_entries[0]` yields `{"key":"https://test.com/gg","value":["msg","popup","url"]}`
2. (Save `.key as $url` for later)
3. Then "emit" all values with `.value[]`
4. For each "emitted" value, produce the string `"\($url)?\(.)=gg"` where `.` is the current value